# Удалённый комментарий "утекает" при просмотре удалённого вопроса / Deleted comment "leaks" in the deleted question view

Tags: дефект, комментарии

[Есть вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604176/%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D0%B3) с одним комментарием. Комментарий был удалён, а после был удалён и сам вопрос.

[There's a question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604176/%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D0%B3) with a single comment. The comment got deleted and afterwards the question itself got deleted.

**Реальное поведение / Actual behaviour:**

Если участник с репутацией 20k или модератор просматривает вопрос, то отображается один скрытый комментарий ([подтверждено 20k участником](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34156249#34156249)):

When a 20k rep user or a moderator views the question, there's a single folded comment ([confirmed by a 20k user](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34156249#34156249)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нажимаю ссылку "показать комментарий" и не вижу ничего кроме пустой строки:

I click the "show comment" link and see nothing except a blank line:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Комментарий на самом деле существует и я могу видеть его с помощью модераторских инструментов:

The comment actually exists and I can reveal it with mod tools:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ожидаемое поведение / Expected behaviour:**

Если участник не имеет привилегии для просмотра удалённых комментариев или не использовал ещё эту привилегию, то ссылки быть не должно.

If the user either has no privilege for viewing deleted comments or didn't use that privilege yet, there should be no link.

---

Я пробовал воспроизвести этот дефект с существующим комментарием, но в таком случае не было ссылки для раскрытия комментариев. После того, как я удалил свой комментарий и стало 2 удалённых комментарий, дефект также не удалось повторить.

I've tried to reproduce this bug with an existing comment, but then there was no link to unfold comments. After I deleted my own comment and then there were 2 deleted comments, the bug also didn't reproduce.

---

Новый удаленный вопрос с таким же поведением: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605493/%D0%9C%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5

---

И ещё другие (не ломать!):

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/676090/178988
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741677

Comment: может на мета-мету запулить?

Comment: @Grundy с локализованными строками? Думаю, будут возмущаться. Договорились же, что разработчики смотрят на баги на нашей Мете.

Comment: Ну вообще говоря, если поймать _steps to reproduce_ - то без разницы :)

Comment: @Grundy да, но у меня пока нет времени чтобы их ловить. )

Comment: Я сначала подумал, что кто-то опять сайтом ошибся :) Русскую версию всё же надо тоже иметь.

Comment: @alexolut да, спешил. Может, переведёте? )

Comment: @NickVolynkin ни за что! :)

Comment: Эм.. Уже починили, или что? https://i.stack.imgur.com/UogHc.png UPDATE: Всё, я прочитал чат :)

Comment: @Qwertiy это я сломал баг обратно. ))